# Почему в VSCode не отображается управление версиями (SOURCE CONTROL?)

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Установил VSCode. Установил GitBash. Зарегистрировался на GitHub. Залил все необходимые плагины и сделал все актуальные настройки. И когда дошел до связки VSCode + GitHub, вдруг увидел, что меню управления, вкладка управления контроля версиями (SOURCE CONTROL) не активна (нет синеньких кнопок, предлагающих создать репозиторий или привязаться к GitHub)

[image: Скрин происходящего прилагается]

Вопрос: возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Помогите пожалуйста решить - как вызвать работоспособность данного меню?

Цель: сохранение настроек и плагинов VSCode при переходе на другой компьютер. Если есть какое либо другое решение, просьба также сообщите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну если вам прям с нуля нужно, то попробуйте удалить папку `.git` (сбросить) и по идее кнопки появятся. Но тогда полность локальный гит сбросится

Comment: папка .git была удалена ещё перед началом установки и VSCode и самого Git (єто у меня уже третья попытка связать их)

Comment: Так у вас же на скрине свернуты секции "source control" и "repositories". Тык на них должен их развернуть.